# php json decode blank page

Tags: php, json

Hello I want to decode json. My code below:

```
<?php
$json = '{"response":{"count":1,"items":[{"id":165983743,"owner_id":170785079,"title":"Ke$ha - Blow","duration":253,"description":"","date":1379017507,"views":1,"comments":0,"photo_130":"http:\/\/cs518121.vk.me\/u170785079\/video\/s_5e5f6f2c.jpg","photo_320":"http:\/\/cs518121.vk.me\/u170785079\/video\/l_dd4ec237.jpg","files":{"mp4_240":"http:\/\/cs518121v4.vk.me\/u170785079\/videos\/500770e51c.240.mp4","mp4_360":"http:\/\/cs518121v4.vk.me\/u170785079\/videos\/500770e51c.360.mp4","mp4_480":"http:\/\/cs1-46v4.vk.me\/p13\/483502b20c4f.480.mp4","mp4_720":"http:\/\/cs518121v4.vk.me\/u170785079\/videos\/500770e51c.720.mp4"},"player":"http:\/\/vk.com\/video_ext.php?oid=170785079&id=165983743&hash=1e417a266e9a3f00"}]}}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print_r ($obj);
print $obj->{'response'}->{'items'}->{'files'}->{'mp4_240'};
```

But I get a blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print_r` should actually print something - your json is correct.

You should do it like this:

```
print $obj->response->items[0]->files->mp4_240;
```

Here's a code working on ideone: http://ideone.com/4xXfOl

**EDIT**: Please whoever downvoted these answers, explain why you do so in comments...

Answer (score 1):

at first u must enable display errors at yours php interpreter

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and then u have to read more  intently the structure of json which u want to travers, the 
items as an array, actually the object keys says it to you: the plural form of item
so the solve is:

```
print $obj->{'response'}->{'items'}[0]->{'files'}->{'mp4_240'};
```

of course I dislike such syntax, it would be better using

```
print $obj->response->items[0]->files->mp4_240;
```

use $obj->{'prop_name'} form when the programm selects accessing attributes dynamicly

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this

```
echo $obj->response->items[0]->files->mp4_240;
```

instead of `print $obj->{'response'}->{'items'}->{'files'}->{'mp4_240'};`